# How to match a new line perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match a line looking like this

```
  (white space)ERROR(some text)(new line)
  (some text)
```

What I have tried is a regex like this and is not working

```
  if (/\sERROR(.*)(\n.*)/){
  }
```

Comment: newline terminates a line, what you are matching against is a __string__ consisting of two __lines__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print `$_` before `if`.

1. are you sure that your string starts with a *single* white space? If not, you need `\s*` instead of `\s`.
2. embedded newlines are rare, are you sure you actually do have it there? If yes, you will need the `s` modifier after the last `/`.

If all else fails, read [the manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: Hi @sds Yes, it is a single space at the start of the string and yes they are embedded newlines.

Comment: @TheBlackCorsair: then you need `s` after the last `/`

Comment: @sds The `/s` modifier only makes `.` match `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/s` modifier: `/\sERROR(.*)(\n.*)/s`. And be careful with greediness of your `(.*)`.